# Click on overlay for closing the modal not working

Tags: next.js, click, overlay, react-modal

I use react-modal in next.js
I can close my modal clicking on the x button, but i want to be able to close it when i press outside of the modal. I searched I found the property       `shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}`, but it doesn't make any difference. If you need more details or code I will give it .
this is my modal:

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import Image from "next/image";

import { XCircleIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline"

Modal.setAppElement("html"); // Set the root element for accessibility

interface ImageViewerModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  imageUrl: string;
}

const ImageViewerModal: React.FC<ImageViewerModalProps> = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  imageUrl,
}) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onRequestClose={onClose}
      contentLabel="Full Image Viewer"
      overlayClassName="modal-overlay"
      shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
      className="modal-center z-30 flex flex-col items-center bg-secondary p-5 drop-shadow-lg rounded-xl"
    >
      <div className="w-full flex justify-end mb-5">
        <XCircleIcon className="w-7 h-7 text-primary cursor-pointer" onClick={onClose}/>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full h-full overflow-hidden">
        {/* Set a maximum width and height for the image container */}
        <Image
          src={imageUrl}
          alt="Full Image"
          quality={100}
          className="modal-image w-full h-full object-cover"
        />
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ImageViewerModal;
```

and this is where I use it

```
<SwiperSlide>
          <Image
            src={Background}
            alt="Thumbnail"
            quality={100}
            placeholder="blur"
            className="cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => openModal(Background)}
          />
        </SwiperSlide>
```

also

```
...
      </Swiper>
      {isModalOpen && 
      (<ImageViewerModal
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onClose={closeModal}
        imageUrl={selectedImageUrl}
      />)}
```

I have the function here:

```
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedImageUrl, setSelectedImageUrl] = useState('');

  const openModal = (imageUrl: any) => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    setSelectedImageUrl(imageUrl);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem guys! And i will put it here for anyone who has the same problem. The problem was here `overlayClassName="modal-overlay"` the css for modal-overlay was broken , i changed it and now it's all good. here is the css

```
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent background */
  z-index: 10; /* Ensure it's above other content */
}
```